# Differentials of Multivariable Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

A soft drink can is h centimeters tall and has a radius of r cm. The cost of material in the can is 0.0015 cents per cm$^2$ and the soda itself costs 0.002 cents per cm$^3$. The cans are currently 10 cm tall and have a radius of 2 cm. Use calculus to estimate the effect on costs of increasing the radius by 0.5 cm and decreasing the height by 0.7 cm.

How may I go about this?

I think I have found my equation, but I do not know how to incorporate the costs.

Comment: do you know the formulas for the volume and surface area of a cylinder with circular top and bottom? $2\pi rh$ gives the lateral surface area and $2\pi r^2$ the area of the top and bottom, while $\pi r^2 h$ gives the volume.

Comment: what is the equation you found?

Answer (score 0):

Recall the volume of our cylindrical can is given by $V=\pi r^2 h$ while its surface area via $A=2\pi rh+2\pi r^2$.

The cost of our soda can can be expressed using something along the lines of:
$$C=(\text{cost of soda per unit volume})\cdot V+(\text{cost of can material per unit area})\cdot A.$$

Here, if we take $C$ to denote the cost of a soda can in cents, we find: $$C(r,h)=0.002\pi r^2 h+0.0015(2\pi rh+2\pi r^2)$$

We can then determine the linearization of the change in $C$ for a given $r,h$ using the total differential: $$\begin{align*}&dC=\frac{\partial C}{\partial r}dr+\frac{\partial C}{\partial h}dh\\\implies &\delta C\approx \frac{\partial C}{\partial r}\delta r+\frac{\partial C}{\partial h}\delta h\end{align*}$$
We're told $r=2,h=10$ and we want to estimate the change in cost following a change in radius of $\delta r=0.5$ and change in height of $h=-0.7$. Can you take it from here?